# How to I turn a python script into a web app?

Tags: javascript, python

Sorry for the noob question, but I created a script that web scrapes data off our sccm server and compares it to programs that need to be pushed to hostnames.

My script works perfectly when I run it in pycharm, but I would now like to make this program available to the other guys on my team via webpage, instead of them needing to borrow my computer everytime, LOL!

Is there a way I can use a javascript front end to let them enter their username, password and serial number, and than based off that info run my script?

I'm not a programmer to be honest so I apologize if this seems like a straightforward thing.

Comment: ....why not just give them the script?

Comment: Like I said I am not the most technical guy. Wouldn't that only work if i downloaded pycharm for them and the libraries i used? or is there an easier way?

Comment: no as long as they have python and the libraries installed it will work. You don't need pycharm. The other way is to present a web service. For that flask is a commonly used library. It really depends what you want to do, the question is broad in scope, therefore there are a lot of possible solutions and implementing them will involve a bit of work, you'd be best to to look at a tutorial.

Comment: You could convert the code to an executable. py2exe or freeze could help here.

Answer (score 1):

This would be difficult for someone to just 'answer' but maybe a rough outline could help?

I'm certainly no professional but this is the way I might approach the issue.

1. create HTML/CSS/JS front end page with a form
2. upon clicking the 'submit' button have the JS take form data and export it into a JSON (just did a quick search on 'execute python script on button click' and things like that to find some implementations of the idea)
3. pass the JSON from the page onto the server and have the python script open up the JSON for the arguments it needs to use
4. python 'wraps' the results up into a JSON file and gives it back to the front end where you have another JS script that unpacks the JSON file and gives it to the user requesting the info. Alternatively, you could have Python put the data into some sort of excel sheet or csv or whatever and have python email the results to the user.

Once all done you'd simply have an instance of Python and all the appropriate libraries sitting on the server ready to use. Pycharm is simply an editor for code. You could theoretically install python itself, and the appropriate libraries needed for your code and just give your folks the .py file itself and have them run the script out of CMD/Terminal and achieve the same result.

Like I say, no professional by any means, and I'm sure I skipped a couple steps but that's a general outline. Obviously in the forms you'd wanna have validation and such to make sure the appropriate data gets used to avoid errors.

Comment: Rather than using Javascript and JSON to ship things back and forth, wouldn't it be easier to set up the Python file as a CGI script that can handle real form POSTs?

Comment: Certainly an option. It's a difficult question to answer in the first place with the breadth of its scope. I was simply offering one rough outline of how to approach it.